# making a shell with C

Tags: c, shell, execvp

i am trying to create a shell using C as a homework but my execvp() doesnt work . it doesnt exe the ls. i am working at a virtual machine lubuntu 32
Thas my outpout any my error message ! [image: http://prntscr.com/6um9xm]

```
if(pid==0){        
       printf("child");                                                                                                            
  char **tokens=tokenizer(hey)//hey is from fgets. tokenizer is fine
printer(tokens);

  //execute ls                                                                                                                                                               
  execvp( ls_args[0], ls_args);

  //only get here if exec failed                                                                                                                                             
  perror("execv failed");

  return 2; //return error status   }
```

Comment: Why are you hiding the error message from us? Is this some kind of trick or prank? It's clearly information that you *have*, so what good could there possibly be in this partial information?

Comment: it doesnt showing any error message its just print "child" and my program continues working till the parent proccess ends. if i do execlp("ls","ls","-l",NULL); its working !

Comment: is `ls` in the path of whatever shell you're using? maybe it should be `/bin/ls` instead.

Comment: @user3135218: In that case, execvp is not failing, since it never returns.  This is a problem with `ls`.  Is the working directory empty?

Comment: @kevin i got my source file at working directory its not empty :(

Comment: @MarcB no i check it my ls is at bin

Comment: `strace` may give you useful hints (`gdb` may as well).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6um9xm the error

Comment: Include the error in your post, people viewing this aren't all going to read the comments.

Comment: @KerrekSB take a look i changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third argument (`a[2]`) has a newline character at the end. `ls` thus complains that it can't find a directory named with a single newline character under your home directory. Fix your command parsing to not include the newline.

Comment: its doing the same with ls

Comment: Please learn to be more descriptive. Tell EXACTLY what you did and what happened.

Comment: i changed it take a loook